# Set-LocalUser password not working for one of my computers in the list, but it was working just minutes ago

Tags: powershell

Given:
PowerShell 5.1
Windows Server 2016 Standard

I'm using PowerShell 5.1 `Set-LocalUser` to set passwords for a couple computers of mine. I've been testing this yesterday and today and it's been working fine. All of a sudden, it's not working for one of the computers. Any thoughts? I didn't see anything in event log

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName Computer1,Computer2 -Credential $credential -ScriptBlock {
    $securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'P@$$w0rd123' -AsPlainText -Force
    Set-LocalUser -Name User1 -Password $securePassword -Verbose
}
```

Error Message:

```
[Computer2] Connecting to remote server Computer2 failed with the following error message : WinRM 
cannot process the request. The following error with errorcode 0x80090311 occurred while using Kerberos authentication: We can't sign you 
in with this credential because your domain isn't available. Make sure your device is connected to your organization's network and try 
again. If you previously signed in on this device with another credential, you can sign in with that credential.  
 Possible causes are:
  -The user name or password specified are invalid.
  -Kerberos is used when no authentication method and no user name are specified.
  -Kerberos accepts domain user names, but not local user names.
  -The Service Principal Name (SPN) for the remote computer name and port does not exist.
  -The client and remote computers are in different domains and there is no trust between the two domains.
 After checking for the above issues, try the following:
  -Check the Event Viewer for events related to authentication.
  -Change the authentication method; add the destination computer to the WinRM TrustedHosts configuration setting or use HTTPS transport.
 Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated.
   -For more information about WinRM configuration, run the following command: winrm help config. For more information, see the 
about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (Computer2:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AuthenticationFailed,PSSessionStateBroken
```

Comment: How is this related to `Set-LocalUser`? It is commented out... And what about the possible causes, do they all *not* apply?

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it but it’s still a problem. It’s just weird that it’s working for a couple days then all of a sudden I get this error.

Comment: I think the comments were just fine. The error message suggests that you cannot remote to Computer2, so you have a problem with `Invoke-Command`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a ***transient* failure**, as implied by this part of your error message (emphasis added):

> The following error with errorcode 0x80090311 occurred while using Kerberos authentication: We can't sign you
> in with this credential **because your domain isn't available**.

However, it may also be due to having previously connected with *different* credentials:

> If you previously signed in on this device with another credential, you can sign in with that credential.

---

To learn more about the specific error:

- You can look up error code `0x80090311` at https://www.hresult.info, (https://www.hresult.info/FACILITY_SSPI/0x80090311), which reveals its symbolic name, `SEC_E_NO_AUTHENTICATING_AUTHORITY`
- A more detailed description of this error can be found in the documentation of the [`InitializeSecurityContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/initializesecuritycontext--kerberos) function for Kerberos:

> No authority could be contacted for authentication.
> The domain name of the authenticating party could be wrong, the domain could be unreachable, or there might have been a trust relationship failure.